# awk question to process lines with zeros across columns

Tags: awk, gawk

Hi I have a file with the following format:

filename is foo.txt

```
abcd 1 0 0 2
abef 2 0 0 0
able 2 1 2 0
able 1 0 0 0
efgh 0 0 0 0
```

I wrote an awk script to delete the row with all columns with 0. But I am getting syntax error.  I am sure this is very simple.

Please can anytime help me fix this?

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1; While($2==0)($3==0)($4==0) {print $0} }' foo.txt
```

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers, upvoting it (or several) and maybe even [accepting the most helpful one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
awk '$2 != 0 || $3 !=0 || $4 !=0 || $5 !=0 ' foo.txt
```

where

- this will filter (grap) line with at least a non zero.
- please not awk will get line, one by one, no need for while.
- also original file won't be edited.

Edit:

"the exact opposite" is a bit fuzzy, however to get line with

- all last field being 0 use `$2 == 0 && $3 == 0 && ...` (`&&` stand for logical and to awk, `||` is logical or)
- at least a 0 use `$2==0 || $3==0 || ...`

if you have many fields, to have line with non zero :

```
awk 'NF>2 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) {print ; next ;}}' file
```

where

- `NF` is number of field
- `NF>2` ensure line have at least 2 field, and for loop terminate.

Comment: One thing I noticed was when I said the exact opposite like awk '$2==0 || $3==0 || $4 ==0 '  my file.txt then the output had columns with all zeros as well as columns with 1 values as here:                                                m 0 0 0 /n
l 0 0 0 /n
i 0 0 0 /n
r 0 0 0 /n
q 0 0 0 /n
p 1 1 0 /n
w 0 0 0 /n
c 0 0 0 /n
F     1 0 1 /n
a 0 0 0 /n

Answer (score 2):

Short GNU ***awk*** solution (to filter out records with zeros):

```
awk -v FPAT='[1-9][0-9]*' 'NF' foo.txt
```

---

*Bonus* ***sed*** alternative approach:

```
sed -E '/^[^[:space:]]+ (0[[:space:]]*){4,}$/d' foo.txt
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
abcd 1 0 0 2
abef 2 0 0 0
able 2 1 2 0
able 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
awk '$2+$3+$4+$5' infile
```

Or even this one if first column always alphabet:

```
awk '$0 ~ /[1-9]/' infile
```

Comment: That first one is rather neat actually,  assuming all numbers are either positive or negative (so that they don't cancel out each other).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ c = 0 } { for (i = 2; i <= NF && c == 0; ++i) { c += ($i != 0) } } c > 0' foo.txt
abcd 1 0 0 2
abef 2 0 0 0
able 2 1 2 0
able 1 0 0 0
```

The script goes through all the fields (skipping the first) and counts how many non-zeroes there are (actually, the counting stops as soon as it finds a non-zero, but that's just a minor optimization).  If there were any non-zeroes, the input record is printed.

`NF` is the number of fields (columns) in the input record (line), and `$i` references field `i`. The default action for `c > 0`, which lacks a `{ ... }` block, is to print the input record.

An equivalent way of writing this script would be

```
awk '{ c = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF && c == 0; ++i) { c += ($i != 0) } } c > 0 { print }'
```

---

You code has the following issues:

1. A `while` statement looks like `while (expression) { code }` whereas you have `while (expression) (expression) ... { code }`. This is a syntax error.
2. The `BEGIN` block is executed *before* the first data is read from the file, hence `$0`, `$1` etc. would have no value within it.